# How can I hide a specific <li>'s and show it when a specific <li> is clicked?

Tags: jquery

What I want to happen is that I want to hide the `<li>`'s whose `parent_id` is equals to other `<li>`'s `group_id`. And show those `<li>`s when the `'<li>'` is clicked?

here is my sample `<ul>` and it is PHP generated.

[image]

PHP Code:

```
foreach($navs as $nav){
                                            echo '<li parent_id="'.$nav['parent_id'].'" group_id="'.$nav['group_id'].'"><a href="#'.$nav['group_id'].'" class="scroll" title="'.$nav['nav'].'">'.$nav['nav'].'</a></li>';
                                        }
```

sample output:
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what you are trying to select. Obviously you can use the ID property to identify a specific li, but generating that inside your php loop will require a conditional statement.  If you can describe which li you are trying to select, I can give you a hand.

Comment: @Mike, base on my sample output. updated! . I want to hide well being salad sub, and only show when well being salad is click, and those values are from database so it is not fixed it will be base on the group_id and parent_id

Comment: @Mike, in my html the first <li> is the well being salad and second and third is the well being salad sub

Comment: You need to use javascript and change the css visibility property.

Comment: @zam664, yes. any sample code will be a big help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$('#navigitions li[parent_id!="1"]').hide();

function hideSubItems(siblings) {
    if(siblings.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    siblings.each(function(){
        var siblings = $(this).siblings('[parent_id="' + $(this).attr('group_id') + '"]').hide();
        hideSubItems(siblings)
    });
}

$('#navigitions li').click(function(){
        var siblings = $(this).siblings('[parent_id="' + $(this).attr('group_id') + '"]').toggle();
        hideSubItems(siblings)
    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g4jGX/8/)

Comment: How can you click it if its hidden?

Comment: sorry, messed the click handler

Comment: can you check again, I made some corrections. check the demo page also

Comment: @ArunPJohny, sir 1 more thing i have many ul in my page, so it affects other if i put id to the specific ul $('#navigitions li[parent_id!="1"]').hide() is just like this right? thanks again

Comment: yes, you need to use `#navigitions li[parent_id!="1"]` and `#navigitions li[parent_id="1"]`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, got another question i updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4jGX/7/) the 2.1.1 won't show

Comment: @ArunPJohny, wow i tried and it works perfeclty! its already dynamic :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = [],
    $li = $('li');

// Collect all group IDs
$li.each(function () {
    var group_id = $.attr(this, 'group_id');
    if ( ! ~$.inArray(group_id, ids) ) ids.push(group_id);
})
// Hide any li whose parent_id is in the ids array
.each(function () {
    if ( ~$.inArray($.attr(this, 'parent_id'), ids) ) $(this).hide();
})
// When an li is clicked, show any li whose parent_id is equal to this group_id
.click(function () {
    $li.filter('[parent_id=[' + $.attr(this, 'group_id') + ']').show();
});
```

Comment: The first condition (parentid = another's groupid) is (should be unless the data is borked) the same as parentid != 1, if that makes things faster.

Comment: @James - With this particular dataset, yes. But I assume this dataset is just a sample of some dynamic output.

Comment: It looks like the question is how to "show only top level items", ie the ones who have no parent.

Comment: It works sir but when I click the sample like "well being salad" it does not show the "well being salad sub"